# Transfer Learning with MobileV2Net

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets, transfer-learning

I am trying to implement transfer learning with MobileV2Net following  from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning .

The above tutorial uses the MobileV2Net model as the base model and uses the "cats_vs_dog" dataset which has the type  `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._OptionsDataset`.
In my case i want to use MobileV2Net as the base model ,  freeze all the weights for different C.N.N layers,add a fully connected layer and fine tune it . The data set i am using is the tiny_imagenet . Following is my code :

```
 ##After pre-processing the data : 
(x_train, y_train), (x_valid, y_valid),(x_test, y_test) = data 

#type(x_train) = numpy.ndarray
#len(x_train) = 1750
##Converting the data to use the pipleine that comes with tf.Data.Dataset
raw_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train))
raw_validation = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))
raw_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
#print(raw_train) gives 
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((64, 64, 3), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.int64)>

## Now i follow everything from the link (given above in problem statement) : 
IMG_SIZE = 160 # All images will be resized to 160x160

def format_example(image, label):
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  image = (image/127.5) - 1
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return image, label

train = raw_train.map(format_example)
validation = raw_validation.map(format_example)
test = raw_test.map(format_example

#print(train) gives
#<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((160, 160, 3), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>

train_batches = train.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_batches = validation.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_batches = test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

#print(train_batches) gives : 
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((?, 160, 160, 3), (?,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
##The corresponding command in the tutorial (which works on cats vs dogs dataset gives) :
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 160, 160, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
```

I also tried using padded_batch() instead of batch() but still the below goes to infinite loop.

```
##Goes to infinite loop
for image_batch, label_batch in train_batches.take(1):
  print("hello")
  pass
image_batch.shape ## Does not reach here 

##The same command in the tutorial gives :
hello
TensorShape([32, 160, 160, 3])

##Further in my case : 
#print(train_batches.take(1)) gives 
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((?, 160, 160, 3), (?,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
##In tutorial it gives : 
<TakeDataset shapes: ((None, 160, 160, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
```

The image_batch is used later in the code.

```
##Load the pre trained Model : 
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
##This feature extractor converts each 160x160x3 image to a 5x5x1280 block of features. See what ##it does to the example batch of images:
feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)
print(feature_batch.shape) ## ((32, 5, 5, 1280))

##Freezing the convolution base 
base_model.trainable = False

##Adding a classification head : 
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch_average.shape) ## (32, 1280)

prediction_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1)
prediction_batch = prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)
print(prediction_batch.shape) ##(32, 1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  global_average_layer,
  prediction_layer
])
```

I have never worked much with tensorflow , any ideas how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

`Padded batch` vs `batch`: [padded batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) is used if the elements inside your dataset are of different shapes whereas [batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) has a requirement that elements in it should have same shape.

The problem with your code is you are not hitting an infinite loop as you are describing. The dataset used by you which is tiny imagenet comprises of 100,000 images and it takes time to iterate through all of them once. If you don't wish to wait for that long, you can change the `pass` to `break` inside your `for` loop and it will come out of loop after first iteration.

There is another operation known as [`repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat). This is used to repeat your dataset the number of times you specify inside it's count parameter. If you set it to -1 however, the dataset will keep looping and in that case, your dataset would have gone to infinite loop.

Comment: I am not training on 100,000 images. The train set is of length 1750(now added in O.P)  . I ran the code again and waited for a while(20 mins) but the loop did not end .
If i try `break` , the loop definitely ends after the first pass but that does not solve the purpose of getting a `TensorShape([32, 160, 160, 3])`. If i use `repeat` with parameter `count=1750`, it still goes into an infinite loop.